# Find source of error in large model when deleting entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In our application we have a large model with ca. 150 different types that are referenced by each other. We are using attributes and reflection to configure the entities and generate the UI, figure out which items to cascade delete etc.

While setting up a new test system, we tried to delete items from the database, but not all, and the deletion was running along until the exception occured:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

We now have a problem finding the source of the error in our code, there is no inner exception, no entity name where to look it up etc. How can we find the source of the error?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are on Debug mode and not Release mode
2. Set your Exception Settings

Open up your Exception Settings
[image: Exception Settings - Window]

Enable the complete set of CLR Exceptions

[image: Exception Settings - Configuration]

Important Note: `F5` is your new best friend.